# how to use oembed api using php for youtube

Tags: php, youtube-api, oembed

I was using WordPress 3.8 and seen **oembed** API that in WP we can just simply put a link and it automatically embedded that video in WP. So, my question is that:
How can i use **oembed** feature? in PHP:
give me some practical example, so i can easily use that in my web

and i have seen this in [Google](https://code.google.com/p/php-oembed/)
used the code stated in above link:

```
<?php
    $manager = ProviderManager::getInstance();
    $obj=$manager->provide("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsROH9YfOZk","object");
    $html=$obj->renderClass();
?>
```

I used that code locally. So,

I appreciate if you tell me that,

Can i implement this API locally means to test ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to pass the id of the YouTube video in a special url :

`http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3D`**ID_VIDEO**`&format=xml`

Example with the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-gQLqv9f4o

We use this url :

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3Dl-gQLqv9f4o&format=xml
```

The output is the XML file generated :

```
<oembed>
    <html>
        <iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l-gQLqv9f4o?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </html>
    <author_name>SoulPancake</author_name>
    <height>270</height>
    <width>480</width>
    <thumbnail_url>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/l-gQLqv9f4o/hqdefault.jpg</thumbnail_url>
    <author_url>http://www.youtube.com/user/soulpancake</author_url>
    <provider_name>YouTube</provider_name>
    <type>video</type>
    <thumbnail_width>480</thumbnail_width>
    <provider_url>http://www.youtube.com/</provider_url>
    <thumbnail_height>360</thumbnail_height>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <title>A Pep Talk from Kid President to You</title>
</oembed>
```

So, all you have to do, it's pass this XML file in function [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) of PHP. Basically you need to read a XML file to get the iframe of the video.

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3Dl-gQLqv9f4o&format=xml");

    echo $xml->title . "<br />"; 
    echo $xml->html;
    echo $xml->author_name;

?>
```

You will have the title of the video, the iframe code and the author of the video.

Comment: he works...I tested it first. Basically i can't help you more with an " not working".