# Get Youtube title from JSONObject to a String

Tags: java, json, youtube

I need to get the titles of Youtube videos but i can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the JSONObject out of the method and into a String.

```
public static String getTitleQuietly(String youtubeUrl) {
    try {
        if (youtubeUrl != null) {
            URL embededURL = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" +
                    youtubeUrl + "&format=json"
            );

            return new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(embededURL)).getString("title");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried doing:

```
String x = getTitleQuietly("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fkcTA7YX44");
            Toast.makeText(PostingGBDTutorial.this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

switching the string parameter to `www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fkcTA7YX44` and even the last 11 characters of the video: `4fkcTA7YX44`

but nothing appeared.

[Where i discovered the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766308/get-title-of-youtube-video)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228744/how-to-use-oembed-api-using-php-for-youtube

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool combination for calling an API and converting the JSON response into a Java object: Retrofit 2 and jsonschema2pojo.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

I won't get into the specifics on how to use them here, but there are a couple key steps...

1. Make an interface for every API call
2. Instantiate the interface using the Retrofit library
3. Generate pojo objects using jsonschema2pojo for deserialization
4. Call the method in your interface and retrieve the deserialized object in the callback.

Good luck!